# a matching symbol was not found in this folder

Tags: c#, dll, sdk, fingerprint, pdb-files

first of all, this is a repetitive question. but things are not same in my case. I have tried most of the solutions. but nothing changed. so, here is the problem,
I have standalone sdk for a fingerprint device and working with visual studio 2015 windows form application. When I tried to debug, I got this message, "The breakpoint will not currently be hit, No symbols have been loaded for this document".

I tried:  Build --> Windows --> Modules to load symbol. but they referred a symbol of one of the dll file (Interop.zkemkeeper.pdb). which I didn't find there instead I found a .pdb file as my project name (AttLogs.pdb). (I know its not logical though) I tried to choose the AttLogs.pdb. and then I got a message saying, "A matching symbol was not found in this folder". So,
1. How do I make my code debug-able? or
2. How do I create a Interop.zkemkeeper.pdb file?
please suggest me anything related or helpfull. I got stuck here for about a week.

[image: error's screenshot]

Comment: using source control or not?

Comment: I am just using the sdk source code. please tell me how can I use source control?

Comment: I did not mean source control can solve it. seems you're not using then

Comment: ok. than what will source control do? should I try? is there any link that I can follow?

Comment: try git/tfs,etc

Comment: @OnickAhmed source control creates "snapshots" of your code for you to roll back to in case of future problems. As an example, look here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-visualstudio/commits/master this is using `git` as Lei mentioned, each item you see there is a backup of the code as it was in that current state.

Comment: @JayGould ok I get it. I'll follow the process next time I code. but what should I do with the pdb problem? any suggestion?

Comment: @OnickAhmed Not a clue unfortunately, best of luck though.

Comment: One of the nastiest VS' errors! So aggravating!